# Iphone GPS alert disabled

Tags: iphone, gps

My application is using geological position (GPS), When I started app it gave me alert like "Would like to use your current location", and I clicked on Don't allow. And its stops working. How to enable this again? Because when I am starting this app again and again this alert is not coming up now. What to do, So that this alert will show up again? How to activate it again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To turn location services on or off:

1) Leave the app and go to your phone's Settings

2) Tap Privacy > Location Services

3) Scroll down to the apps name and toggle the switch to On or Off

Answer (score 0):

The message will only be offered once to the user, not a second time. You as an developer will have to present a message to the user telling them to go into the settings and enable location service for your app.